# The limit as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, infinity

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac1{2x}}\right)$$

Can anyone explain how to get this?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply by
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}}.$$
The top then simplifies nicely.

Comment: ok so I did what you said and I got- x(-1/2x)/(1+sqrt1+1/2x). Then I multiplied x with -1/2x to cancel out the x . After that, I just multiplied -1/2 with 1/2 to get -1/4. I know this is the answer but i was wondering I approached it correctly?

Comment: Your previous comment did not get completed, probably because you pressed the Enter key. You should get limit $-\frac{1}{4}$.  Added: Yes, what you did is right, since the (new) bottom approaches $2$,

Answer (score 1):

Setting  $\dfrac1{2x}=h,x=\dfrac1{2h}$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac1{2x}}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+h}}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-(1+h)}{2h(1+\sqrt{1+h})}$$

Now cancel $h$ as $h\ne0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}})\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}-\frac12 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}}=-\frac14$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for the behavior of $$x\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac1{2x}}\right)$$ when $x$ goes to large values, you could remember that, when $y$ is small, Taylor expansion is $$\sqrt{1+y}= 1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ Now, replace $y$ by $\frac1{2x}$ and then $$x\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac1{2x}}\right)\approx x\Big(1-(1+\frac1{4x}-\frac1{32x^2})\Big)=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{32 x}$$

Developing $$\sqrt{1+y}$$ to first order gives the limit; pushing to second order shows how the expression approaches the limit.